# Won't echo message after update in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This code works, I believe. But it doesn't echo the confirmation or error.

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){      

        $servername="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username)or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db("web", $conn);

                    $mypassword=$_POST['pwd'];
                    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
                    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
                    $address=$_POST['address'];
                    $location=$_POST['location'];

                    $sqlsel="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$id' AND pwd='$mypassword' ";
                    $result=mysql_query($sqlsel,$conn) or die(mysql_error());  

                    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

                    if($count==1){  
                        $sql="UPDATE users " .
                        "SET fname = '$fname', 
                        lname = '$lname',
                        address = '$address', 
                        location = '$location'" .
                        "WHERE pwd = '$mypassword'";

                        $res = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
//IS THIS CORRECT TO REFRESH THE PAGE???
                        header("Location: edit.php?id=" . $id);
//IT WON'T ECHO....
                        echo 'Information updated.';
                        }

                    else {
//ALSO THIS ONE...
                    echo print "Invalid Password.";
                    }


                mysql_close($conn);
}
?>
```

It seems to work on my other form but it won't work on this edit form.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After header location, anything won't work. 
what you could do is

```
header("Location: edit.php?id=" . $id . "&msg=1");
```

then on edit.php
just get $_GET["msg"] like

```
if isset($_GET["msg"])
echo 'Information updated.';
```

Comment: header("Location: edit.php?id=" . $id . "&msg=1");
    if (isset($_GET["msg"])){
       echo 'Information updated.';
     }

like this?? the page is updated but it doesn't echo...

Comment: it works now.!! so i should have two separate files to make it work.. coz i'm only working on one file.. >.<

Answer (score 1):

You have sent redirection headers, after that browser starts to redirect and doesnt echo. Remove the header call.

Comment out this part

```
//header("Location: edit.php?id=" . $id);
```

Also

```
echo print "Invalid Password.";
```

Should be

```
echo "Invalid Password.";
```

Comment: @user1947562 why would you need to refresh the page while it is processing? If it is refreshed like that then you wont see an echo because $_POST will be lost. And even if you manage to retain it then it would mean Double update

Comment: ahm.. i used refresh because after the update the data in the edit form is still the old data until it is refreshed. but when i go the the user form it is updated.

Comment: then either one of those can "conveniently" take place. Either an echo or a refresh

Answer (score 0):

when header location is declared it will redirect page ONLY when its the first php/html declared

anything after wont work or display

Comment: wow! it works! thanks!!! 

but now how can i refresh the page.? i used the header location to refresh the page after the update.